# Zk Spring CustomComponent reference bean

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, zk

I am developing a ZK custom component something like

```
public class MyComponent extends HtmlMacroComponent implements java.io.Serializable
{
    //some dependences.which are injected by Spring
}
```

In ZK you can register your custom components using a file `lang-addon.xml` which has the following format.

```
<component>
   <component-name>customComponent</component-name>
   <component-class></component-class>
   <macro-uri>myZUL</macro-uri>
 </component>
```

In `<component-class>` is the reference to my Java file which I have as a Spring bean with all the references to other beans.

I want to know how can I reference the Spring bean in:

```
<component-class></component-class>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

```
@VariableResolver(org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver.class)
public class MyComponent extends HtmlMacroComponent implements java.io.Serializable {

  @WireVariable
  private SpringBean springBean;

  public MyComponent () {
      Selectors.wireVariables(this, this,
              Selectors.newVariableResolvers(getClass(), HtmlMacroComponent.class));
      Selectors.wireComponents(this, this, false);
      Selectors.wireEventListeners(this, this);

  }
}
```

Good Luck!